Unable to receive location and temperature using WEATHERAPI in Flask app
I'm trying to create an app to generate the weather at a certain location based on the IP address visiting my site. My function is supposed to get their IP address using ip-api.com and then send that IP to the waetherapi API and get it's weather and location, then return it in JSON format.
These are my original functions to get the IP address, location and weather:
def get_ip(ip):
    visitor_ip = requests.get(f"https://ip-api.com/json/{ip}")
    response =  visitor_ip.json()
    city = response.get("city", "Unknown")
    return city


def get_weather(city):
    api_key = os.getenv("WEATHERAPI_KEY")
    weather_reply = requests.get(f"http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key={api_key}&q={city}&aqi=no")
    weather =  weather_reply.json()

    if "current" in weather:
        temperature = weather['current']['temp_c']
    else:
        temperature = "N/A"

    if "location" in weather:
        city_new = f"{weather['location']['name']}"
    else:
        city_new = "N/A"
    
    return temperature, city_new

Here is the expected  JSON response from the weatherapi.com website for the API using the IP address I provided:
http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=**************&q=165.73.223.224&aqi=no
Response Code:
200....
Response Headers:
{
  "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
  "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
  "CDN-PullZone": "93447",
  "CDN-Uid": "8fa3a04a-75d9-4707-8056-b7b33c8ac7fe",
  "CDN-RequestCountryCode": "GB",
  "Age": "0",
  "x-weatherapi-qpm-left": "5000001",
  "CDN-ProxyVer": "1.04",
  "CDN-RequestPullSuccess": "True",
  "CDN-RequestPullCode": "200",
  "CDN-CachedAt": "07/07/2024 13:18:56",
  "CDN-EdgeStorageId": "1054",
  "CDN-Status": "200",
  "CDN-RequestId": "d953ffe88adfc6650d8a7d0d88cdbb90",
  "CDN-Cache": "MISS",
  "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=180",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Date": "Sun, 07 Jul 2024 13:18:56 GMT",
  "Server": "BunnyCDN-DE1-1054",
  "Via": "1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.0)"
}

Response Body
{
    "location": {
        "name": "Ifo",
        "region": "Ogun",
        "country": "Nigeria",
        "lat": 6.82,
        "lon": 3.2,
        "tz_id": "Africa/Lagos",
        "localtime_epoch": 1720358270,
        "localtime": "2024-07-07 14:17"
    },
    "current": {
        "temp_c": 30.3
    }


This is the  expected output:

{
   "client_ip": "165.73.223.224",
   "greeting": "Hello, Mark! The temperature is 30.3 degrees Celsius in Ogun Nigeria" 
   "location": "Ogun Nigeria", 
}


This is what I get:

{
  "client_ip": "165.73.223.224",
  "greeting": "Hello, Someone! Unfortunately, I could not determine your location",
  "location": "Unknown"
}


q=165.73.223.224  why is the IP address here? Shouldn't it be the resolved city or Unknown? Please [edit] your question to show how you're calling each of get_ip() and get_weather() and what you're doing with the results
